# adb reboot recovery does not reboot samsung galaxy tab 10.1 into recovery mode

Tags: android, adb, reboot, samsung-mobile

I am trying to root my Samsung Galaxy tab 10.1 and following the instructions here -

http://samsungmobileclub.com/how-to-root-and-install-ics-custom-rom-on-galaxy-tab-10-1/

However, when I type adb reboot recovery, the tablet shuts down but does not reboot. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I confirm that bug even on not rooting usage
so you have to switch it on by hand ... is there a place to send bug report to manufacturer ?